# Python printing before/after different lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, bbcode

I have created some code long ago which helps to create a table in BBcode used in forums.

```
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
while True:
        UserInput = input("")
    if counter2 == 0:
        print ("[tr]")
    print ("[td][center]Label\n" + "[img]" + str(UserInput) + "[/img][/center][/td]")
    counter += 1
    counter2 += 1
    if counter % 5 == 0:
        print ("[/tr]")
```

So if i input Image1.jpg ~ Image7.jpg on seperate lines, the output is as shown below

```
> [tr] 
> [td][center]Label[img]Image1.jpg[/img][/center][/td] 
> [td][center]Label[img]Image2.jpg[/img][/center][/td] 
> [td][center]Label[img]Image3.jpg[/img][/center][/td] 
> [td][center]Label[img]Image4.jpg[/img][/center][/td] 
> [td][center]Label[img]Image5.jpg[/img][/center][/td] 
> [/tr]
> [td][center]Label[img]Image6.jpg[/img][/center][/td] 
> [td][center]Label[img]Image7.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
```

Currently, the code only inserts [/tr] at the end of ever 5 images.How does one make it so that [/tr] is also printed at the end of output no matter how many jpgs are entered?

How can I print [tr] at the start and join it with the line below, and then not print again until a [/tr] has been printed?

Apologies for my crap English & explanation skills.

(Current progress)

```
counter = 0
while True:
    UserInput = input("")
    if counter == 0 or counter % 5 == 0:
        print("[tr]", end = "")
    print ("[td][center]Label\n" + "[img]" + str(UserInput) + "[/img][/center][/td]")
    counter += 1
    if counter % 5 == 0:
        print("[/tr]")
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation so it accurately reflects your code.

Answer (score 1):

After reading what you wrote 5 times I believe what you want is:

```
    print("[tr]")
    while True:
        counter = 0
        UserInput = input("")
        if UserInput == "exit":
            exit(0)
        print("[tr]", end = "")
        while (counter !=5):
            print ("[td][center]Label\n" + "[img]" + str(UserInput) + "[/img][/center][/td]")
            counter += 1
        print ("[/tr]")
    print("[/tr]")
```

So what happens here is you print [tr] in the same line as the first print from the inside while as you wanted. the [/tr] is in a new line but you can put it in the same by adding end = "" to the second print as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've reworded and provided an example now. I tried your solution, inputting 5 lines; it ended up printing the same line 5 times before proceeding to the next line in the sequence, probably my fault due to poor english.

Comment: @diu.lei I'm still not sure exactly what you want. In your example isnt it missing a [tr] after [/tr]? Or do you just want it at the beggining of everything and a [/tr] every 5 ? try to put a full example maybe

Comment: Yeah it was missing a [tr] well spotted, Basically want the a [tr] at the start on the same line as line 2 in the example, and then another [tr] every 5 lines

Comment: I edited it added the print before and after the while to do it at the beginning and at the end. Also does it every 5 lines. Added an exit condition so that it doesn't get permanently stuck in the while cycle. You can change it around but it should be something similar

Comment: I juggled the code around, and got it to quite similar to how I wanted it. The problem with your code was the while counter part looped and just printed 1 line of my input 5 times as opposed to doing what we presumed it would and only print line after every 5 lines. Now the only thing I need to figure out is how the code can detect it has printed all the userinput lines and output an ending [/tr] line.

Comment: I guess a better way to put it is, how do i detect the amount of lines in userinput and then I can manoeuvre my way around the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the functions.  Get the list of images, then process it:

```
def bbcode(images):
    for i in range(0,len(images),5):
        print('[tr]')
        for image in images[i:i+5]:
            print(f'[td][center]Label[img]{image}[/img][/center][/td]')
        print('[/tr]')

def get_images():
    images = []
    while True:
        image = input('Image? ')
        if not image: break
        images.append(image)
    return images

images = get_images()
bbcode(images)
```

You can do it as one long script, but it isn't as clear:

```
count = 0

while True:
    image = input('Image? ')
    if not image:
        break

    count = (count + 1) % 5
    if count == 1:
        print('[tr]')
    print(f'[td][center]Label[img]{image}[/img][/center][/td]')
    if count == 0:
        print('[/tr]')

if count != 0:
    print('[/tr]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the result with some commentary. To update for your specifications, just set the `max_item_blocks` variable to whatever you want.

```
### your main body element with {} to pass a number
element = '[td][center]Label[img]Image{}.jpg[/img][/center][/td]'

### The number of "blocks" you want to print.
max_item_blocks = 3

### Define a start value of 1
start = 1

### Our simple loop with join() function
while max_item_blocks > 0:

    ### End value is start + 5
    end = start + 5

    print('[tr]\n' + '\n'.join([element.format(i) for i in range(start, end)]) + '\n[\\tr]')

    ### Start takes ending value
    start = end

    ### Ending value is now start + 5
    end = start + 5

    ### Reduce our block counts by 1
    max_item_blocks -= 1
```

Output for 3 blocks:

```
[tr]
[td][center]Label[img]Image1.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image2.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image3.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image4.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image5.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[\tr]
[tr]
[td][center]Label[img]Image6.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image7.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image8.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image9.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image10.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[\tr]
[tr]
[td][center]Label[img]Image11.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image12.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image13.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image14.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[td][center]Label[img]Image15.jpg[/img][/center][/td]
[\tr]
```

Comment: Does not work for me, I normally paste a block of links containing jpgs (cropped out from example) when I tried this, just returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" upon using /

Comment: @Diu.Lei Hi.  SyntaxError covers a lot of stuff. I just retried this in my IDE and it worked okay.  One thing that might work: If you have Notepad++ (or another text editor that allows regular expressions) can you try copying the script in there and then replacing any tabs (`'\t'` or the TAB button) with 4 spaces?  also, I use single quotation marks, so maybe checking those to make sure they're compatible with your setup might help. Let me know if anything worked or if there's still issues!